# mysql function call vs hardcoded data

Tags: mysql

I've been developing a backend for a website that has an inventory of products. The inventory has an "in-and-out" system where products are delivered to the customers(this will be the decrement) and also products are received from the manufacturers(this is increment). I have 2 separate tables for these procedures. I was wondering what is the most efficient way in determining the product's current stock based on the in and outs?

The following are my options:

1. Put a column under the product table that contains the current stock. Here I will decrement or increment it depending on the process.
2. Use a mysql function that will determine the sum of the received quantity minus the sum of delivered quantity.

Also here are some key factors to consider:

1. Both receiving and delivery table can contain thousands of data.
2. Data integrity.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I would rather choose option 2. In my opinion it's better to fire an SQL Query, than storing the stock values into the database.

Comment: But what about if there are thousands of data? Does this slow the function call?

Comment: In our tables that contain the product description, sku, etc, we had inventory fields there.  We did actual and virtual. Virtual was based on order fulfillment. We didn't seem to have any problems. At the height of our sales year we would process 75,000 orders.

Comment: So are you suggesting that option two is most efficient?

Comment: If you need a lot of joins for the product counting, this could be a valid argument. If so a view could be a good choice, see *http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp*